# Dynamodb update sort key value in single update using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I have DynamoDB table with the following fields:

Primary Partition key => user_id

Primary Sort key => conversation_id

LSI Sort key => date_time

Sample table data

```
+---------+--------------------+-----------------------+
| user_id | conversation_id    | date_time             |
+---------+--------------------+-----------------------+
|      10 |    aaaa            | 2017-03-11 10:05:26   |
|      10 |    bbbb            | 2017-03-11 10:06:28   |
|      10 |    cccc            | 2017-03-11 10:07:34   |

|      11 |    aaaa            | 2017-03-11 10:05:26   |
|      11 |    bbbb            | 2017-03-11 10:06:28   |
|      11 |    cccc            | 2017-03-11 10:07:34   |

|      12 |    aaaa            | 2017-03-11 10:05:26   |
|      12 |    bbbb            | 2017-03-11 10:06:28   |
|      12 |    cccc            | 2017-03-11 10:07:34   |
+---------+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

I have **current date_time** which is need to update. How to **update date_time** where **conversation_id = "aaaa"**.
I can update using for loop with **user_id and conversation_id**. But without for loop how i can update..?

Comment: It is simply not possible to update the item without providing the hash and sort key. The update API doesn't support it.

Comment: @notionquest How about this? Main table has partition key and some other sort key, `date` is just a plain attribute. Create a GSI with `date` as sort key. Does GSI update the `date` sort key w/o any issues and using 1 WCU (if < 1Kb) if we update `date` on main table?

Comment: Please note that application can't directly write to the index (GSI or LSI).